# How do I filter Fiddler sessions to show only a specific remote computer

Tags: android, fiddler

I've followed this http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid to allow me to view http traffic from my Android tablet on Fiddler installed on my PC. It works well.

However, I am seeing ALL traffic, including that from my local PC - which is still overly chatty despite closing down all my browsers. I would like to use a filter to show a specific device. The filters page doesn't appear to allow this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your first and simplest step is to untick the **Capture Traffic** option on Fiddler's File menu; this will unregister Fiddler as the system's proxy.

Beyond that, you could write a rule inside Rules > OnBeforeRequest:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oSession["x-ProcessInfo"])) { 
    oSession["ui-hide"] = "localprocess"; 
}
```

This will hide any traffic from a process on your local PC, thus showing only remote traffic.

If you had *multiple* remote computers and wanted only traffic from one of them, you'd write your rule to examine the `oSession["X-CLIENTIP"]` flag.

Comment: I knew the answer would lie in FiddlerScript somehow. This worked a treat.

Comment: "untick the Capture Traffic" worked great for me. I'm capturing an emulator android machine. Thanks!